# How to get link from a tag which contains span text

Tags: python-3.x

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
text1 = """<table id="klogo" class="kcontainer" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="https://sports.com" target="_blank" style="color:#a5a5a5;text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#a5a5a5;text-decoration:none;">
        <img src="https://sports.atlas.com.png" alt="Rentvine" title="Rentvine" height="50" border="0" style="display:block; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:5px; border-style:none; height:50px; background:none;"/></span></a>
        <br/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<tr>
<table class="buttons" align="center" width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <td align="center">
        <table class="button" align="center" cellspacing="0" width="225" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="225" height="50" bgcolor="#2175bc" style="height:50px;display:block;font-family:'helvetica neue','helvetica','arial',sans-serif;font-size:17px;border:solid 1px #2175bc;border-radius:6px;">
                <a href="https://sports.atlas.com/rugby" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;line-height:50px;width:100%;display:inline-block;">
                <span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:50px;">View Sport<span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>"""
text2 = """<table id="khdr" class="kcontainer" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="20" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" style="height:20px;display:block;font-size:17px;" align="center">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

                            <!--main-->
                            <table id="kmain" class="kcontainer" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <!--body-->
                                    <table align="center" width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:auto;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family:'helvetica neue','helvetica','arial',sans-serif;line-height:25px; text-align:left;">
                                            <br/>
                                            <span style="font-size:18px;line-height:25px;color:#545454;">


    <h4>Sport main</h4>

    <div>
        <table class="buttons" align="center" width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <table class="button" align="center" cellspacing="0" width="225" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="225" height="50" bgcolor="#2175bc" style="height:50px;display:block;font-family:'helvetica neue','helvetica','arial',sans-serif;font-size:17px;border:solid 1px #2175bc;border-radius:6px;">
                <a href="https://sport.atlas/football" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;line-height:50px;width:100%;display:inline-block;">
                <span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:50px;">View Sport<span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

spans = soup.select_one("a > span",text=re.compile("View Sport"))
print(spans)
print(spans.parent["href"])
```

There are two text (text1 and text2). I need to get the url which has the span text "View Sport" for text2 I am getting the solution but for text1 I am unable to get. Is there any solution to get the required url.

Required solution:

1. https://sports.atlas.com/rugby (from text1)
2. https://sport.atlas/football (from text2)

Comment: @ScottHunter spans = soup.select_one("a > span",text=re.compile("View Sport")) I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text1 = """<table id="klogo" class="kcontainer" align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="https://sports.com" target="_blank" style="color:#a5a5a5;text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#a5a5a5;text-decoration:none;">
        <img src="https://sports.atlas.com.png" alt="Rentvine" title="Rentvine" height="50" border="0" style="display:block; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:5px; border-style:none; height:50px; background:none;"/></span></a>
        <br/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<tr>
<table class="buttons" align="center" width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <td align="center">
        <table class="button" align="center" cellspacing="0" width="225" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="225" height="50" bgcolor="#2175bc" style="height:50px;display:block;font-family:'helvetica neue','helvetica','arial',sans-serif;font-size:17px;border:solid 1px #2175bc;border-radius:6px;">
                <a href="https://sports.atlas.com/rugby" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;line-height:50px;width:100%;display:inline-block;">
                <span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:50px;">View Sport<span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>"""

text2 = """<table id="khdr" class="kcontainer" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="20" bgcolor="#e9e9e9" style="height:20px;display:block;font-size:17px;" align="center">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

                            <!--main-->
                            <table id="kmain" class="kcontainer" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <!--body-->
                                    <table align="center" width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:auto;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family:'helvetica neue','helvetica','arial',sans-serif;line-height:25px; text-align:left;">
                                            <br/>
                                            <span style="font-size:18px;line-height:25px;color:#545454;">


    <h4>Sport main</h4>

    <div>
        <table class="buttons" align="center" width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <table class="button" align="center" cellspacing="0" width="225" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="225" height="50" bgcolor="#2175bc" style="height:50px;display:block;font-family:'helvetica neue','helvetica','arial',sans-serif;font-size:17px;border:solid 1px #2175bc;border-radius:6px;">
                <a href="https://sport.atlas/football" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;line-height:50px;width:100%;display:inline-block;">
                <span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:50px;">View Sport<span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text1 + text2, "html.parser")

links = soup.select("a:-soup-contains('View Sport')")
print(*[l["href"] for l in links], sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
https://sports.atlas.com/rugby
https://sport.atlas/football
```

Comment: How to use regex in a:-soup-contains('View Sport') if i need to add View Food

Comment: @BenDavid You can use just `View `: `soup.select("a:-soup-contains('View ')")`, or use `soup.select("a:-soup-contains('View Sport', 'View Food')")`